SignalR in serverless mode not passing message onto function app SignalRTrigger
I've got Azure SignalR setup in serverless mode connected to a .net 6 function app running in in-process mode.
I have a method with a HttpTrigger that sends a message to an event on a specific SignalR hub and another with a SignalRTrigger that listens for messages events on the same hub with the same category.
namespace Signalr_wrangler
{
    public static class SignalRMessageFn
    {

        [FunctionName("index")]
        public static IActionResult GetHomePage([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "content", "index.html");
            return new ContentResult
            {
                Content = File.ReadAllText(path),
                ContentType = "text/html",
            };
        }


        [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "cozmostest")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
        {
            return connectionInfo;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(SignalRTest))]
        public static void SignalRTest([SignalRTrigger("cozmostest", "messages", "signalRTest")] InvocationContext invocationContext, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogDebug("Function called from signalr:" + invocationContext.Arguments.Length);
        }        

        [FunctionName("message")]
        public static Task SendMessage([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] 
        HttpRequest req, [SignalR(HubName = "cozmostest")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages, ILogger logger)
        {
            var result=  signalRMessages.AddAsync(
            new SignalRMessage
            {   
                Target = "signalRTest",
                Arguments = new[] { "<here_can_be_multiple_objects>" }                
            });

            result.Wait();
            logger.LogDebug("message result " + result.Exception?.ToString());
            return result;

        }      
    }
}

When I call the HttpTrigger, it successfully responds and send the message to SignalR,

However SignalR never seems to pass that message on to the trigger in my function app as it only is only logging the http trigger not the signalr trigger.

The same seems to happen with the function app hosted in azure or running locally in debug
I've configured the function app and SignalR as per
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service-trigger?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example
I've tried variations on case in the category/target,
I'm not seeing ant CORS errors in the logs bug have added CORS exemptions anyway.
And I'm using the latest Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService version (1.14.0) from nuget
For reference here is the code to my index.html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Azure SignalR Serverless Sample</h1>
        <div id="messages"></div>
        <script         src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.7/signalr.min.js"></script>
<script>
let messages = document.querySelector('#messages');
const apiBaseUrl = window.location.origin;
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(apiBaseUrl + '/api')
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();
    connection.on('signalRTest', (message) => {
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = message;
  });

  connection.start()
    .catch(console.error);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Any advice would be appreciated

Please share more details about the issue.

Can you share code for index.html file?

I'm not really using the index, I'm expecting to see the SignalRTest function called and logs added to app insight
either way I've added it to the question

Could you, please, provide the code for your Azure Functions as text. Posting screenshots of code is not the preferred way of providing code samples according to StackOverflow's guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20ask%20a%20good#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20ask%20a%20good

No worries I've changes the code screenshots to text source
